# wordpress admin security

Tags: security, hacks

[image]

I scan my website using different tool but it shows no malicious script.
But when i see in admin dashboard i see strange symbol square below body tag.

i tried to check admin index file,root index file but there is nothing there.Some one place this script.

Also when i tried to take backup its not allowing me to take.using backupwordpress  plugin.
how ever all other things working but still some thing wrong in admin.

HOw to detect and remove this.

Comment: Switch to a default theme. Still got the problem? Deactivate all plugins. Still got the problem? Re-install WordPress. Otherwise, re-activate your plugins one by one until the problem comes back - you've found the troublemaker.

Answer (score 1):

It may be coming from theme or plugin you are using. Sometimes developers forget to remove any `echo` statement (or any other debugging approach) which they use while developing.

You can first disable all plugins. If this still comes up, then it is somewhere there in the active theme. If this goes away after you disable all plugins, then try enabling plugin one by one. This way you can know the plugin responsible for this.

If you have technical knowledge in wordpress/php, then you can fix this yourself. Else the better option will be contacting the plugin author and ask them for a fix. This will help other users who are also using the same plugin.

Comment: Thanks.it was in plugins.However what do you recommend for wp security.I install wordperss better security but some time it happens it locks out andmin and other problems and it becomes impossible to delete or deactivate this plugin